# What is the difference between the two given scenarios?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom-events

I have a piece of code in html and Javascript with two scenarios presented differently as:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="number" onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 ? true : !isNaN(Number(event.key))" />

<input type="number" onkeydown="checkForNumber(event)" />

</form>


</body>

<script>
  function checkForNumber(event) {

    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 ) {

      return true;
    } else {
      return !isNaN(Number(event.key));
    }

  }
</script>
</html>
```

The first input type is working as desired i.e it is allowing only numeric values . But when I moved the onkeydown thing to a function and then tried to call that it is not working as expected i.e. it is allowing me to enter some characters like 'e', '-', '+', '.' ... .
What is the difference between those two? And how can I achieve first scenario with function call?

Comment: Any idea how to achieve it in angular ?? Because in angular, "return" statement giving error if we are using "return" in html template.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the `onkeydown` function has a `return` statement.

In the second example, the `onkeydown` function **does not** have a `return` statement. (It calls `checkForNumber` and discards the return value).

Comment: Thanks buddy !! Any idea how to achieve it in angular as angular html doesn't allow return statement?

Answer (score 0):

You are not ***returning*** anything in the second input type. Update your code to

```
 <input type="number" onkeydown="return checkForNumber(event)" />
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="number" onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 ? true : !isNaN(Number(event.key))" />

<input type="number" onkeydown="return checkForNumber(event)" />

</form>


</body>

<script>
  function checkForNumber(event) {

    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 ) {

      return true;
    } else {
      return !isNaN(Number(event.key));
    }

  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy !! Any idea how to achieve it in angular as angular html doesn't allow return statement?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same functionality using function call, you need to add return keyword before the function call

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="return checkForNumber(event)" />
```

Comment: Thanks buddy !! Any idea how to achieve it in angular as angular html doesn't allow return statement?